# Can the US police be replaced with minorities volunteer squads?

Tags: united-states, police, racism, discrimination, minorities

As long, as [George Floyd](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/05/31/us/george-floyd-investigation.html) killing reveals huge problems in the US police departments, [discrimination and racism](https://www.ukessays.com/essays/criminology/discrimination-and-racism-in-the-us-police-force.php) in the US police, some [reform](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-53188189) was started. But it isn't clear, would it change anything fundamentally. It seems, that the whole system should be changed.

From the other side, if police discriminates minorities, replacement of the police with minorities may work.

**Can the US police be replaced with minorities volunteer squads?**

**EDIT**

*It should be emphasized, that those squads should be formed of minorities representatives ONLY. Under minorities I mean any nation/gender/any other minorities. Such police can, additionally, prevent the public facts of discrimination/abusement.*

Comment: This seems like a strawman proposal. Who proposed such a thing?

Comment: @Fizz, I wondered myself but trolls usually don't have that much reputation. So I gave it the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/puar.12956
This study found that black officers are more likely to kill black suspects than white officers.

Comment: So only people with melanin content falling above a certain as yet TBD threshold can enforce laws? I must say, this sounds a lot like what the civil rights champions fought to end.

Comment: @acpilot Look at their other questions – this is a troll question, just flag and downvote, no need to consider it seriously.

Comment: Good point. I took the bait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It could be done. It would probably be a *very* bad idea.**

- Proper policing is highly skilled work. There are some who think that typical US police are not **trained enough** before they go out on the streets. I can think of nobody who says that they are overtrained.
- Hiring more "minorities" (how do you define that?) might work, unless the trainers then inoculate racist behaviour in their recruits.
- Requiring police to live in their precinct area might be another option, but it would complicate transfers and promotions within the departments.

Comment: First point is very good - I missed that. The second one - my emphasize is on the fact, that those squads should contain from minorities representatives ONLY. Third - but why should they? That would be some local militia. Rephrased question a bit, to put more emphasize on the second point.

Comment: @user2501323, some 60% of the US population are identified as "non-hispanic white." That suggests heterosexual white men are less than a third -- a clear minority. And the reason to have cops live in the area they police is to prevent an us-vs-them mentality, which is a big part of the problem.

Comment: @user2501323, I wanted to point out a certain problem with your proposal. How about *poor* whites? Can they apply? Recent immigrants from Eastern Europe? And when did Italian-Americans stop being a non-rivileged minority in your eyes? How about Asian-Americans?

Comment: @o.m., I think when people mean minority, they mean making up a small part of the population relative to other groups, not whether you make 50% or not

Comment: @SomeGuy, that means African-Americans would not qualify in the South? Yes, I get it that there could be a definition which specifies minorities that are getting discriminated against, but ISTR that the biggest winners of affirmative action were white middle-class *women* ...

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple major issues with this:

- Members of a volunteer police force still need money to live. Fortunately for them, police work allows for "ethically questionable sponsorship opportunities".
- One of the issues with some US police forces is lack of training for the wide range of situations they are asked to deal with. It's unlikely that a volunteer force would be able to resolve this lack of professional training.
- A common complaint is that US police forces enjoy too many powers, specifically conditional immunity for a variety of crimes up to and including manslaughter. Giving these powers to a volunteer police force (also known as "Vigilantes") with less training might not resolve this problem.
- The assumption that people belonging to minorities are not racist is at best unproven.
- Excluding people from certain professions solely due to their race is about as racist as it gets.